# Symfony 2: How to avoid the sessions table being dropped by doctrine migrations?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm new to migrations, and I'm trying to stick to the automatically generated ones:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
$ php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

The problem is that this drops my sessions table. What can I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I am late to this question, but figured i would offer a suggestion.

import the session tables into your entities. even if you don't use it through the interfaces it creates, it will allow Doctrine to keep track of the tables, so that it knows they are ment to be there.

see: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Answer (score 30):

Another option is simply to tell Doctrine to ignore the table.  You can use the `schema_filter` option as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19489299/328817).

So, if your table is called `sessions`, add the following to *config.yml* (Symfony < 4) or *doctrine.yaml* (Symfony >=4 ):

```yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
      # standard database config here
      schema_filter: ~^(?!sessions)~
```

We had a large number of tables to ignore, so we took the opposite approach - we told Doctrine to only consider tables which began with a certain prefix, and set up listeners to ensure all our Doctrine-managed tables had a prefix.  The use of listeners for table prefixes is documented at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/sql-table-prefixes.html and there's a SO post about the Symfony side of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504073/how-to-setup-table-prefix-in-symfony2/8366548#8366548).

Comment: I can confirm that this works nicely in Symfony4 if you add it to doctrine.yaml

Answer (score 0):

When you say "sessions table" I guess you're meaning the sessions table for PdoSessionStorage? (just to be sure we're talking about the same thing :-) )

I had a similar issue, and the only persistent (and non-complex) solution was simply to put your sessions in another database (and update the configuration accordingly). But this requires the permission to create an additional DB.

If you don't have this possibility, I'll look in to some other solution, but maybe the above mentioned one works for you :-)

Comment: So you don't have the possibility to put all the PdoSessionStorage stuff (basically the sessions table) in another database?

Comment: Yes but it's more trouble I think. And I don't know if having an extra db connection is good for performance. Wouldn't it add overhead?

Comment: You definitely need not to use another dedicated database for just the session table. As @Sam has already posted the answer above, it is enough to configure doctrine to ignore session table. I'm writing this in 2020, Sam's answer was in 2013 and this (currently) invalid answer belongs to 2011; that's why I don't want to downvote the answer since it may be valid in 2011.