# How to configure naming strategy in Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I read the [chapter](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html) about Doctrine naming strategies in the manual. Unfortunately I don't understand where I have to put the configuration code.

In order to get an underscore naming strategy I should use this code:

```php
$namingStrategy = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy(CASE_UPPER);
$configuration()->setNamingStrategy($namingStrategy);
```

Where should I put this?

I'm on Symfony 2 — I guess this matters when it comes to configuration.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Configure it in `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    # ...

    orm:
        # ...
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
```

Comment: I think this only works on the latest dev version (https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/90). I'm on 2.2 which does not include this configuration option.

Comment: I'm on Symfony SE 2.1.2 which includes DoctrineBundle that supports this configuration option. Haven't you upgraded yet? ;)

Comment: Sorry for the noise. It's working fine. Since I'm having multiple entity managers, I had to learn that the option is set per entity manager.

Comment: This feature available in `Doctrine` since version `2.3` (https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html)

Comment: I do not know what I must put there in order to load the naming strategy of my own bundle

Comment: How did you know it? I didn't find it in the doc.

Answer (score 18):

For multiple entity managers:

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                # ...
```

Comment: Ran into this issue, after adding a "default" entity manager.
'Unrecognized options "naming_strategy, a
  uto_mapping" under "doctrine.orm"'

Pretty silly i did not figure it out. But a quick search helped pointed me here. Thanks!

Comment: How can we solve this above an error? We are faced the same error in our symphony project.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a console.php file to run the CLI you might put it there.

```
<?php

//something...

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);

$namingStrategy = new UpperCamelCaseNamingStrategy();
$config->setNamingStrategy($namingStrategy);

$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

//something else...
```