# How to prefix sequence names?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I know [how to set up a table prefix in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504073/how-to-setup-table-prefix-in-symfony2), but now I'd like to do the same for postgres sequences. How can I do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Not familiar at all with postgres sequence but how about using [`setSequenceGeneratorDefinition`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html#1545-1562) in a way inspired from the answer you linked?

Comment: This could be the solution, I don't know. The fact is, I do not have the time to try it, that's why I opened a bounty. Try it, and if you provide a full, working solution that I can copy-paste, the bounty is for you

Comment: I have posted an untested answer. If it doesn't work and doesn't make sense, I will delete it. Keep me posted!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the answer from here: [How to setup table prefix in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504073/how-to-setup-table-prefix-in-symfony2)

1. Open up your bundle's Resources/config/services.yml and add:

   ```
   parameters:
       mybundle.db.sequence_prefix: myprefix_
   ```
2. Add a new service:

   ```
   services:
       mybundle.sqprefix_subscriber:
           class: MyBundle\Subscriber\SequencePrefixSubscriber
           arguments: [%mybundle.db.sequence_prefix%]
           tags:
               - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
   ```
3. Create MyBundle\Subscriber\SequencePrefixSubscriber.php

   ```
   <?php
   namespace MyBundle\Subscriber;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

   class SequencePrefixSubscriber implements \Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber
   {
       protected $prefix = '';

       public function __construct($prefix)
       {
           $this->prefix = (string) $prefix;
       }

       public function getSubscribedEvents()
       {
           return array('loadClassMetadata');
       }

       public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $args)
       {
           $classMetadata = $args->getClassMetadata();
           if ($classMetadata->isInheritanceTypeSingleTable() && !$classMetadata->isRootEntity()) {
               return;
           }


           if ($classMetadata->isIdGeneratorSequence())
           {
               $newDefinition = $classMetadata->sequenceGeneratorDefinition;
               $newDefinition['sequenceName'] = $this->prefix . $newDefinition['sequenceName'];

               $classMetadata->setSequenceGeneratorDefinition($newDefinition);
               $em = $args->getEntityManager();
               if (isset($classMetadata->idGenerator)) {
                   $sequenceGenerator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Id\SequenceGenerator(
                       $em->getConfiguration()->getQuoteStrategy()->getSequenceName(
                           $newDefinition,
                           $classMetadata,
                           $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()),
                       $newDefinition['allocationSize']
                   );
                   $classMetadata->setIdGenerator($sequenceGenerator);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Reference: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html

The documentation says `READ-ONLY` for the `sequenceGeneratorDefinition` property so I think it is cleaner to use the setter than changing the value manually (but there is no getter so we just use the public property value).

Comment: Accepted, upvoted, bounty granted. I love Stack Overflow.

Comment: Actually, it does not work everywhere... It is not taken into account when I try to persist an entity. I'll try to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit (and the bounty). The metadata is usually cached, have you tried to look in the cache folder to see if the data was there? (under `annotations@`)

Comment: I looked for "sequence" in the app/cache directory, but I can't find any anything :(

Comment: I solved the problem, but my solution won't work with strange sequence names because of an injection problem.

Comment: If you do `$args->getEntityManager()` you don't get the right value?

Comment: @cheesemcafly : didn't notice this argument! This could be the solution, let me try

Comment: This looks good, but I'm still unable to get the `targetPlatform`...

Comment: `$args->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()` should work, but can't test right now!

Comment: Thanks, I'll test when I'm home!

Comment: Works! You really deserve your bounty!