# Symfony 6.2 translation error 'Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "ext_translations_id_seq" does not exist' postgresSql

Tags: php, symfony, uuid

I have a controller action:

```
#[Route('/store', name: 'store', methods: 'POST')]
public function store(Request $request): Response
{
    $myEntity = new MyEntity();

    $form = $this->createForm(MyEntityFormType::class, $myEntity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $form->submit($request->toArray());

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            /** @var MyEntity $validatedMyEntity */
            $validatedMyEntity = $form->getData();

            $this->doctrine->persist($validatedMyEntity);

            $this->doctrine->flush();

            $this->doctrine->refresh($validatedMyEntity);

            return $this->getJsonResponse($validatedMyEntity);
        }
    }
    elseif (!$form->isSubmitted()) {
        dd('not isSubmitted...');
    }
```

When i call the endpoint, i got error message at `$this->doctrine->flush();` row the following error message:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
    "title": "An error occurred",
    "status": 500,
    "detail": "An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation \"ext_translations_id_seq\" does not exist\nCONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $1 = '...'",
    "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\TableNotFoundException",
    "trace": [
    .
    .
    .
        {
            "namespace": "Doctrine\\DBAL",
            "short_class": "Connection",
            "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection",
            "type": "->",
            "function": "lastInsertId",
            "file": "/home/vagrant/Projects/tests/Trendency/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Id/IdentityGenerator.php",
            "line": 48,
            "args": []
        },
    .
    .
    .
    ]
}
```

There is a strange thing, when i call it from a Command, it working well.
I tried to start `doctrine:shchame:validate` & `doctrine:shchame:update --force` commands, but it hasn't any effect.

Extra `doctrine.orm.mappings` has been in `doctrine.yaml` as the following:

```
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: attribute
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/src/Translatable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_translator:
                type: attribute
                prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/src/Translator/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslator # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
```

Form is:

```
class MyEntityFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'id',
                UuidType::class,
                [
                    'required'          => false,
                ])
            ->add(
                'title',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required'          => true,
                    'constraints'       =>  [
                        new NotBlank(['message'=>'Add Title!']),
                        new NotNull(['message'=>'Title cannot be null!']),
                    ],
                    'invalid_message'   => "Bad title type"
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'description',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required'          => true,
                    'constraints'       =>  [
                        new NotBlank(['message' =>'Add Description!']),
                        new NotNull(['message'  =>'Description cannot be null!']),
                    ],
                    'invalid_message'   => "Bad Description type"
                ]
            );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'        => MyEntity::class,
            'csrf_protection'   => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

I suspect, this error is related `stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle`, or the uuid type of id but since this string not found in it's repo, no other idea to solve.
Does have anybody idea, how to solve it?
Thanks for helps in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.
The `ext_translations_id_seq` name is a sequence name in the `stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle` `gedmo_translator` feature.

I was add a dynamic table prefixing logic, can be found [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/sql-table-prefixes.html)

Unfortunatelly this table / sequence doesn't cooperates well with linked Doctrine Event Listener, so i was needed to add handler for SEQUENCES.

So i added a SequencePrefixSubscriber also based on [this description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380177/how-to-prefix-sequence-names) .
After that the original sequence names also prefixed yet, and everyone worked except the `ext_translations_id_seq`, because the UnitOfWork during persist refreshes that ClassMetaData, and searched unprefixed sequence name during id generation.

To handle it i simply created an exempt case for `Translation` and `AbstractTranslation` classes, are uses this sequence. This way it will not be overwrited later, and id can be generated.

Here is the complete `loadClassMetadata()` method:

```
public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    /** @var ClassMetadata $classMetadata */
    $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

    if ($classMetadata->isIdGeneratorSequence())
    {
        $newDefinition = $classMetadata->sequenceGeneratorDefinition;
        $newDefinition['sequenceName'] = $this->prefix . $newDefinition['sequenceName'];

        $classMetadata->setSequenceGeneratorDefinition($newDefinition);
        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        if (isset($classMetadata->idGenerator)) {
            $sequenceGenerator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Id\SequenceGenerator(
                $em->getConfiguration()->getQuoteStrategy()->getSequenceName(
                    $newDefinition,
                    $classMetadata,
                    $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()),
                $newDefinition['allocationSize']
            );
            $classMetadata->setIdGenerator($sequenceGenerator);
        }
    }

    if (in_array($classMetadata->getName(), [Translation::class, AbstractTranslation::class])) {
        $sequenceName = $this->prefix . self::STOF_TRANSLATION_SEQ_NAME;
        $idGenerator = new IdentityGenerator($sequenceName);
        $classMetadata->setIdGenerator($idGenerator);
    }
}
```

I was add only the part wrapped by in_array condition.

Naturally booth Subscriber and EventListener should be registered under services index in `services.yaml` .