# add prefix in table name without change in annotation of Doctrine

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using **Doctrine2** with **codeigniter**. my project has created but i have to add prefix in database table. In codeigniter I have solved this issue with dbprefix `$db['default']['dbprefix']`.
But Doctrine not support it because Entity classes are not created with prefix. So it can't find Table.

I want to add table prefix in doctrine also without change in Entity class name of doctrine. Is there any possibility to add some prefix.

I have search **TablePrefix** Class but this class not working in my Doctrine library.

Previously Project created without prefix table name like "user" and entity annotation has also created with "User". But now I added prefix in all table "my_user"

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a table prefix by using Doctrines event manager as described in the Doctrine documentation here:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/sql-table-prefixes.html

In a previous question, simshaun has given a good example of how to implement this in symphony:

[How to setup table prefix in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504073/how-to-setup-table-prefix-in-symfony2)

Comment: :- Doesn't happend same error as previous user table not found

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.user' doesn't exist'

Comment: Correct link [Doctrine. ORM. Documentation. SQL-Table Prefixes](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/cookbook/sql-table-prefixes.html)