# How to configure api platform to have one prefix per all entites from module?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a following directory structure:

```
config
    - packages
        - api_platform.yaml
src
    - backoffice
        - entity
           - employee.php
    - products
        - entity
            - printer.php
```

I want to configure api_platform in a way so that every entity from /backoffice/entity has route prefix /backoffice, every entity from /products/entity has route prefix /products and so on.

So for example with configuring only api_platform.yaml, I would be able to go to:

```
GET /backoffice/employees/1
```

or

```
GET /products/printers/5
```

without configuring the prefixes manually for each entity.

I know I can do this per entity using the RoutePrefix annotation but I was wondering if there is a way to do this globally for each of my domains/bundles.

Comment: Hi, seems a duplicate question, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34413140/1155833)

Comment: @rkeet the link you posted is about table prefixes in the database. My question is about prefixing routes in API platform configuration

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that. In that case you're probably looking for [subresources](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/)

Comment: Hi @MichałŚnieżko, did you figured out the solution for this? i'm facing the same problem. Thanks