# Doctrine: How to insert variable in annotations?

Tags: php, orm, annotations, doctrine, yaml

I need to prefix by `sf4__` and **dynamically** all my database tables columns like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="sf4__posts")
 * ...
*/
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to do it via a `php` or `yaml` file.

Comment: That sounds like a nightmare. Just use a different database?

Comment: Meaning... **No** ?

Comment: It seems to be possible going by [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/sql-table-prefixes.html), but that doesn't make it sound like a good idea :)

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8366548/2270041 answer