# Symfony4 Doctrine2 custom NamingStrategy how to

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I am just starting with Symfony4 / Doctrine2. So, I need to implement Doctrine2 custom `NamingStrategy` but cannot find any documentation/samples besides this one: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html and this answer [How to setup table prefix in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504073/how-to-setup-table-prefix-in-symfony2/23860613#23860613). They do not explain much in terms how to do this in relations to the Symfony4. I understand that I need to create a class that implements `NamingStrategy` interface, so where should I put this class in the Symfony4 folder structure, in the `src/Entity`?

Then I need to register the class as a service, it must be easy for a seasoned Symfony developer to know, but as I am just starting, would be nice to have some elaboration on this. Thanks, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Anyway, I have managed to figure it out myself.

First I have created custom naming strategy class extending UnderscoreNamingStrategy. I have placed it under src/Service/, still not sure if this is the right place for it to go to in the folder hierarchy.

Then I have registered this class as a service by adding following to the end of the the config/services.yaml :

```
...

# Naming Strategy
app.naming_strategy.custom:
    class: App\Service\CustomNamingStrategy
    autowire: true
```

After that I have configured the doctrine to use this custom naming strategy by editing config/packages/doctrine.yaml as follows:

I have commented out:

```
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

and added under it:

```
    naming_strategy: app.naming_strategy.custom
```

Comment: Thanks. This was totally eluding me for many hours. The documentation is so bare, basically states you need a class extend some other class then it dumps you into the darkness to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you! That was much more helpful than the official documentation.