# Doctrine2 Ignore table of database

Tags: symfony, filter, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2 and I want to generate an ORM of my database but I don't want select all  tables of the db.

For example, in this db :

- Table 1 has no primary key
- Table 2 is normal

I want to choose ONLY Table 2 with this command:

```
doctrine:mapping:convert --from-database yml ./src/Application/TestBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --filter="Table2"
```

I have an error :

> Table Table_1 has no primary key. Doctrine does not support reverse engineering from tables that don't have a primary key.

Ok I know , but I don't want my table 1 in my ORM. When my table 1 has primary key i can filter the tables. I've seen 
[Generating a single Entity from existing database using symfony2 and doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371600/generating-a-single-entity-from-existing-database-using-symfony2-and-doctrine), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I needed to import only one table from MySQL into Symfony. So my command was `php  app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force StrategioMainBundle yml`  In config.yml : `schema_filter: ~^(fundinfo1)~`

Comment: Can you please post the solution as an answer and accept it? (this question appears in the *unanswered* list of symfony2 question) Thanks.

Comment: @StephanVierkant I'm not the OP. It looks like the user won't edit the question, we can add the answer in a wiki answer.

Comment: I've posted the answer as a community answer and removed my comments.

Comment: @StephanVierkant do we need to add a small introduction to the answer in order to explain that it was the solution from the OP?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, but feel tree to add it :).

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring the table was the solution:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: ~^(?!Table1)~
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use Doctrine2 without Symfony then you should add this line to your bootstrap:

```
// With this expression all tables prefixed with Table1 will ignored by the schema tool.
$entityManager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setFilterSchemaAssetsExpression("~^(?!Table1)~");
```

the whole bootstrap looks like

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;


// Include Composer Autoload (relative to project root).
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$paths = array(__DIR__."/doctrine/entities");

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
//$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/doctrine/yaml"), $isDevMode);

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
  'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
  'user'     => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'dbname'   => 'database',
);

/** @var $entityManager \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);


// Set the other connections parameters
$conn = $entityManager->getConnection();


$platform = $conn->getDatabasePlatform();
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');


// With this expression all tables prefixed with t_ will ignored by the schema tool.
$conn->getConfiguration()->setFilterSchemaAssetsExpression("~^(?!t__)~");
```

Comment: What if you are using Symfony but needing to have your entities share tables from a Laravel application database that has some tables without primary key?

Comment: Every entity class must have an identifier/primary key: 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys

Answer (score 4):

In recent versions of the Doctrine bundle one has to configure schema filter on the connection level, so:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default: # <- your connection name
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
        schema_filter: '#^(?!table_to_exclude)#'
```

Answer (score -2):

Doctrine first validates your tables and only then executes the command. 
So you should always have valid DB schema in order to make any operations with it.